# UIActivityViewController's share feature without the view controller

Tags: ios, uiactivityviewcontroller

Is there a way to skip the modal presentation of a `UIActivityViewController` and launch the built-in edit view of each of the services (i.e. Twitter) directly?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want directly present an SLComposeViewController:

```
if ([SLComposeViewController isAvailableForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter]) {
    SLComposeViewController *tweetSheet = [SLComposeViewController 
        composeViewControllerForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter];
    [tweetSheet setInitialText:@"Initial Tweet Text!"];
    [self presentViewController:tweetSheet animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

BTW, the code is lifted straight from [Ray's awesome blog](http://www.raywenderlich.com/21558/beginning-twitter-tutorial-updated-for-ios-6).

Comment: +1 just need add the Social.framework libray and then #import <Social/Social.h>   thanks brother!!